# Autodesk Infrastructure Studio - Enable WMS

Tags: wms, autodesk

With only a couple hours experience this is very likely user error but I have "Autodesk Infrastucture Studio 2013" installed with a few "Data" nodes and "Layers" nodes.  I can right-click a child of the "Data" node and select "Enable WFS..." and it gets added to my WFS service BUT I when I right-click a child of the "Layers" node I do not have the corresponding "Enable WMS" layers.  Neither is the *Enable WMS/WFS* toolbar item enabled.

Any thoughts on what might be causing of "Enable WMS" not getting enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Autodesk Infrastructure studio you have to enable wms on a mapdefinition. This is not very logical as it will -in reality- be enabled on the layers within that mapdefinition.

(you could also enable from mapguide maestro, there you can enable per layer)